# $V$ decomposition into cyclic subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, $\dim(V) = n$
>
> Let $f: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear nilpotent map such that $f^m = 0$ for an integer $m$.
>
> A cyclic subspace is the subspace generated by $x$ noted as:
>
> $\langle x\rangle = \operatorname{span}\bigl(x, f(x), f^2(x), ... , f^{m-1}(x)\bigr)$
>
> With $f$ nilpotent, prove that $V$ can be decomposed into a direct sum of cyclic subspaces $\langle x\rangle$:
>
> $$V = \bigoplus_i \langle\, x_i\rangle $$

---

We suppose that $n > m$.

We have $\langle x\rangle$ is an invariant subspace of $f$.

There is $F$ such that: $V = \langle x\rangle\oplus F $

with: $\dim(F) = n - m$

We consider the restriction of $f|_F$ on $F$ and form a cyclic subspace again but I don't know how to proceed to get the full decomposition.

Comment: You can try (strong) induction on the dimension  of $V$. B.t.w., you only have $1\le \dim\langle x\rangle\le m$.

Comment: @Bernard Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: Well, $\dim F\le n-1$, so you can apply the inductive hypothesis if you can find an $F$ invariant by $f$.

Comment: @Bernard For $y \notin <x> $, we have $f(y) \notin <x>$. This means, that $f(F) \subset F$, again I can form the cyclic subspace generated by $y$. This can be repeated until $V$ is covered. When doing induction, I am used to assuming the result is true for $n$ and prove it for the case of $(n+1)$. I can't see how to proceed by induction in this case. If you could write an answer, I'll be very grateful, thank you.

Comment: *Strong* induction uses as induction hypothesis that  a property $P(k)$ is true for all $k\le n$, not only that $P(n)$ is true.

Comment: Okay, suppose that for $V$ such that $dim(V) = k \leq n$, we can decompose $V$ into a direct sum of invariant cyclic subspaces. If we have $W$ such that $dim(W) = n$, we can form a cyclic subspace invariant by $f$. Then, we will have: $W = <x> \oplus F$, such that $dim(F) \leq n$. We apply the induction hypothesis and we get the result. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (b.t.w., in math mode  dim is coded `\dim` to have it uppercase).

Comment: @Bernard Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi The main problem is that you have to choose $F$ as an $f$-invariant subspace.

Comment: @egreg We have: $V = <x> \oplus F$. For $y \notin <x>$, we have $f(y) \notin <x>$, which means $f(y) \in F $. Is it correct?

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi No, sorry.

Comment: @egreg What am I missing?

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi $\langle x\rangle\oplus F=V$ doesn't mean that $V=\langle x\rangle\cup F$.

Comment: You're right, how to show that $F$ is $f$-invariant subspace?